# Foreign key in Ajax POST request in Django

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-views

I have some problems with my web app . I need to specify user in my Ajax request. When I try to add new item I get an error:
*TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got .* Is the any solutions ?
Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = AddTask(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.cleaned_data
            form.save()         
            user_membership = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)      
            expence_object = model_to_dict(Task.objects.get(pk=user_membership))
            return JsonResponse({'error': False, 'data': expence_object})
```

**models.py**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
    is_published=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    usertask=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT,  null=True, blank=True)
```

**Ajax form**

```
        $('#taskpost').submit(function (e) {
                // console.log("Creating the book");
                e.preventDefault();
                // get the form data
                var formData = {

                    'title': $('#id_title').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    encode: true,
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'create/',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                }).done(function (data) {
```

Comment: Not sure if this solves everything, but this line: `expence_object = model_to_dict(Task.objects.get(pk=user_membership))` raise an exception because it expects an integer and you're passing a model instance. It should be: `expence_object = model_to_dict(Task.objects.get(pk=user_membership.pk))`

Comment: @revliscano I changed it and I got an error : * raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
main.models.Task.DoesNotExist: Task matching query does not exist.* **but** object was created (without Foreign key).

Comment: Oh, of course. I see what the error is. Let me elaborate my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting those errors because you're not handling things correctly in your views. First of all, when creating your `Task` object, you're saving it without setting an `usertask` value, therefore null is set.

On the other hand, when trying to fetch the just-created object here `Task.objects.get(pk=user_membership)` you're doing this wrong because you're passing an `User` instance to the parameter pk. It should be an integer.

Furthermore, for what I see, what you're trying to accomplish here: `expence_object = model_to_dict(Task.objects.get(pk=user_membership))` is to get the just-created model, but that's totally unnecessary in your case and also you're doing it wrong. Please, try the following code instead:

```
form = AddTask(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # form.cleaned_data  <-- This line is unnecessary here too
        obj = form.save(commit=False) # Prevent saving before assigning usertask
        obj.usertask = request.user
        obj.save()
        expence_object = model_to_dict(obj)
        return JsonResponse({'error': False, 'data': expence_object})
```

When you save a form that is based on a model, it returns the saved instance of the model. So there's no need to save it to the database and then make a new query to get it back. Just assign it to a variable (`obj` in this case) and do all the other things you need to do.